# How to prevent Time Input Keyboard being cropped down?

Tags: android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

[image: On my mobile]I am new at android developing. I am facing very  strange problem. I have a EditText which input type is Time. But as you see in the 1st picture, some bottom part is missing when the keyboard pops up. As a result, I cant input 0. I tried to solve by using SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST methode, but none worked for me. I dont know is this the problem with my phone keyboard ? Emulator is fine while running.

[image: On emulaor]

Comment: In my browser there is no 1st picture showing. No pictures at all.

Comment: I am sorry. Now you will see it.

Comment: with "Emulator is fine" you mean to say, that the cropping problem is not showing in your (Android Studio?) emulator, but it is happening on a physical phone? What is the screen size in pixels of your emulator and of your phone?

Comment: Yes, I meant that exactly. I have added one more picture of my emulator on the post. emulator pixels 1080 X 1920, where my phone is 720 X 1280 pixels. Now I see that this problem happens with my phone (samsung's) default keyboard. I have another keyboard of about same size which shows the keyboard rightly. What is the reason??